# running a shell command that is quoted

Tags: perl, bash, readline

In my Perl program I get to a point where I have a variable that has the following:

```
echo -e \"use\nseveral\nlines\"
```

I would like to run this command through the shell (using `exec`) as

```
echo -e "use\nseveral\nlines"
```

I tried `eval` on the variable before I passed it to `exec`, but that interpreted the `\n` and changed them to newlines.

EDIT:

Note that I am given the variable and do not have control over how it is input. Thus, given that the variable was input as such, is there a way to "unquote" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, you should use `q{}` or `qq{}` (or `qx{}` for execution) to avoid complicated quote escaping.

This should work for you (using `q{}` to avoid interpolating `\n`):

```
my $str = q{echo -e "use\nseveral\nlines"};
```

Now, you can execute it using `qx`:

```
qx{$str}
```

Comment: Thanks, mvp. My question should be clearer: I am given the variable and do not have control over how it is input. Thus, given that the variable was input as such, is there a way to "unquote" it?

Comment: In the end I was able to gain access to the library, It was being manually quoted. So the unquote I would have to reverse the manual quotes with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass

```
echo -e \"use\nseveral\nlines\"
```

to the shell, it passes the following three args to the `exec` systems call:

```
echo
-e
use\nseveral\nlines
```

How does one create that last string? Here are a few ways:

```
"use\\nseveral\\nlines"  # Escape \W chars in double-quoted strings.
'use\\nseveral\\nlines'  # Escape \ and delimiters in single-quoted strings
'use\nseveral\nlines'    #    ...although it's optional if unambiguous.
```

The corresponding Perl command would be therefore be

```
exec('echo', '-e', 'use\nseveral\nlines');

system('echo', '-e', 'use\nseveral\nlines');

open(my $fh, '-|', 'echo', '-e', 'use\nseveral\nlines');
my @output = <$fh>;
```